# Mantra for marriage and love?

Tags: marriage

Which vedic mantras should one chant for a better love life? I specifically was looking for a mantra which can help one to meet a new quality partner as well as a citation to the original passage in the rig veda where it is mentioned

There are a lot of kamadev mantras I am finding on the internet but they all lack proper citation to vedas and there are different variations

Answer (score 1):

In the two reviews of the Atharva Veda, there are three incantations for the Lord Kama.
If you just need a short mantra, but according to the Vedic model, without tantric influences (without additional bijas, with the exact Vedic name of this God), then this will be: OM  kA mA ya  na maH

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! Could you please add source of that mantra? like verse number.

Comment: This mantra is present in the text of Mantra Mahodadhi, but along with tantric mantras, therefore a bija klIM is added to it.

Comment: Would you please add the verse number ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is one. In Atharvaveda 6:82.

> आगछत आगतस्य नाम गृह्णाम्यायतः । इन्द्रस्य वृत्रघ्नो वन्वे वासवस्य
> शतक्रतोः ॥१॥
>
> येन सूर्यां सावित्रीमश्विनोहतुः पथा । तेन मामब्रवीद्भगो जयामा वहतादिति
> ॥२॥
>
> यस्तेऽङ्कुशो वसुदानो बृहन्न् इन्द्र हिरण्ययः । तेना जनियते जायां मह्यं
> धेहि शचीपते ॥३॥

This is for a suitable wife. For a better husband Atharvaveda 2:36 is suitable.

> आ नो अग्ने सुमतिं संभलो गमेदिमां कुमारीं सह नो भगेन । जुष्टा वरेषु
> समनेषु वल्गुरोषं पत्या सौभगमस्तु अस्यै ॥१॥ सोमजुष्टं
> ब्रह्मजुष्टमर्यम्ना संभृतं भगम् । धातुर्देवस्य सत्येन कृणोमि पतिवेदनम्
> ॥२॥ इयमग्ने नारी पतिं विदेष्ट सोमो हि राजा सुभगां कृणोति । सुवाना
> पुत्रान् महिषी भवाति गत्वा पतिं सुभगा वि राजतु ॥३॥ यथाखरो
> मघवंश्चारुरेष प्रियो मृगाणां सुषदा बभूव । एवा भगस्य जुष्टेयमस्तु नारी
> संप्रिया पत्याविराधयन्ती ॥४॥ भगस्य नावमा रोह पूर्णामनुपदस्वतीम् ।
> तयोपप्रतारय यो वरः प्रतिकाम्यः ॥५॥ आ क्रन्दय धनपते वरमामनसं कृणु ।
> सर्वं प्रदक्षिणं कृणु यो वरः प्रतिकाम्यः ॥६॥ इदं हिरण्यं
> गुल्गुल्वयमौक्षो अथो भगः । एते पतिभ्यस्त्वामदुः प्रतिकामाय वेत्तवे ॥७॥
> आ ते नयतु सविता नयतु पतिर्यः प्रतिकाम्यः । त्वमस्यै धेह्योषधे ॥८॥

For translation read this [answer.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44632/are-there-any-mantras-shlokas-to-bring-about-marriage-with-a-suitable-partner)

Answer (score 0):

dhyānu prathama juga makhabidhi dūjēṃ. dvāpara paritōṣata prabhu pūjēṃ..
kali kēvala mala mūla malīnā. pāpa payōnidhi jana mana mīnā..

In the first age, contemplation; in the second age, sacrifice; in the Dvāpara age the Lord is propitiated through worship. This age of Kali, however, is simply corrupt and the root of all impurities, where the mind of man wallows like a fish in the ocean of sin.

nāma kāmataru kāla karālā. sumirata samana sakala jaga jālā..
rāma nāma kali abhimata dātā

In this terrible age the Name alone is the wish-yielding tree, the very thought of which puts an end to all the illusions of the world. The Name ‘ Rāma ’ is the bestower of one's desired object in this age of Kali.

- Ramcharitmanas, Baal Kanda, Naam Vandana.