# Are there any Mantras / Shlokas to bring about marriage with a suitable partner?

Tags: mantras, marriage, shloka

Do Hindu Scriptures have any mantras / shlokas / prayers by which a girl may get married without delay to a good man?

This question may appear to be asking for personalized advise or as primarily opinion based, but it is not. Please don't close it as it is a legitimate and general question based on Hinduism / Hindu prayers that will help many.

Comment: For men, the mantra from Siddh sampat stotra helps, which in turn is the part of argala stotra. The mantra is, पत्नीं मनोरमां देहि मनोवृत्तानु सारिणीम् ।
तारिणींदुर्गसं सारसागरस्य कुलोद्भवाम्  ।। Meaning, (Oh devi,) give me a wife in harmony with my mind; that makes the life journey easier for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Vyankatesh Stotra**

Written by saint Devidas in Marathi, its [Sanskrit equivalent](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/venkateshastotram.html) is one from BhramadPuran. The one in marathi mentions the following in its Fal-Shruti (what fruit!?):

> लग्नार्थियाचे व्हावे लग्न । धनार्थियासी व्हावें धन ।
> पुत्रार्थियाचे मनोरथ पूर्ण । पुत्र देऊनि करावे ॥ ८३ ॥

The one wishing of Marriage, money and child will be blessed with it.

> इच्छा धरुनि करील पठण । त्याचें सांगतों मी प्रमाण ।
> सर्व कामनेसी साधन । पठण एक मंडळ ॥ ९२ ॥

For all sorts of work, Recite for 1 Mandal (42 days) by keeping its wish.

> क्षय अपस्मार कुष्ठादि रोग । इत्यादि साधनें प्रयोग ।
> त्यासी एक मंडळ सांग । पठणे करुनि कार्यसिद्धी ॥ ९४॥

For failure, Epilepsy and Kushtrog (a disease), and all other works Do it from ones hart for 1 mandala (42 days), success is without doubt.

Its Suggested to recite it daily for marriage, for a child there are other Guidlines found within the fal-shruti. And all other sorts of works it must be recited for 42 days with faith and devotion. It can be found [here](https://www.bhaktiras.net/shri-vyankatesh-stotra/).
Ofcourse there are other stotras or mantras suggested depending upon Horoscopes of Native. This one can be recited without any complicated rules and can be recited by all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. Is it essential to read the marathi version, or is it ok to read the sanskrit version?

Comment: Marathi version is preferred, while sanskrit can also be read and then ask lord vyankatesh your whises. For marriage read it daily till the marriage actually happens. Sometimes people leave it once marriage is decided. The reason marathi version is preferred is Saint Devidas has asked lord himself to make it happen. Infact one can actually see vyankatesh by reciting it. One of my questions was inspired by it: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/43503/21353

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Proxy- I hope you see this and reply. Please do give me the detailed procedure for this. Is this recited at midnight? For how many days for marriage purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a charm for a desirable wife in **Atharvaveda 6:82.**

> **आगछत आगतस्य नाम गृह्णाम्यायतः । इन्द्रस्य वृत्रघ्नो वन्वे वासवस्य शतक्रतोः ॥१॥**

> **येन सूर्यां सावित्रीमश्विनोहतुः पथा । तेन मामब्रवीद्भगो जयामा वहतादिति ॥२॥**

> **यस्तेऽङ्कुशो वसुदानो बृहन्न् इन्द्र हिरण्ययः । तेना जनियते जायां मह्यं धेहि शचीपते ॥३॥**

**Meaning**

> I call the name of him that comes here, that hath come here, and is arriving; I crave (the name) of Indra, Vritra's slayer, the Visava, of hundredfold strength.
> The road by which the Asvins carried away as a bride Sûryâ, Savitar's daughter,'by that road,' Bhaga (fortune) told me, 'thou shalt bring here a wife'!
> With thy wealth-procuring, great, golden hook, O Indra, husband of Sakî, procure a wife for me that desireth a wife!

For a desirable husband, there is a charm in **Atharvaveda 2:36.**

> **आ नो अग्ने सुमतिं संभलो गमेदिमां कुमारीं सह नो भगेन । जुष्टा वरेषु समनेषु वल्गुरोषं पत्या सौभगमस्तु अस्यै ॥१॥
> सोमजुष्टं ब्रह्मजुष्टमर्यम्ना संभृतं भगम् । धातुर्देवस्य सत्येन कृणोमि पतिवेदनम् ॥२॥
> इयमग्ने नारी पतिं विदेष्ट सोमो हि राजा सुभगां कृणोति । सुवाना पुत्रान् महिषी भवाति गत्वा पतिं सुभगा वि राजतु ॥३॥
> यथाखरो मघवंश्चारुरेष प्रियो मृगाणां सुषदा बभूव । एवा भगस्य जुष्टेयमस्तु नारी संप्रिया पत्याविराधयन्ती ॥४॥
> भगस्य नावमा रोह पूर्णामनुपदस्वतीम् । तयोपप्रतारय यो वरः प्रतिकाम्यः ॥५॥
> आ क्रन्दय धनपते वरमामनसं कृणु । सर्वं प्रदक्षिणं कृणु यो वरः प्रतिकाम्यः ॥६॥
> इदं हिरण्यं गुल्गुल्वयमौक्षो अथो भगः । एते पतिभ्यस्त्वामदुः प्रतिकामाय वेत्तवे ॥७॥
> आ ते नयतु सविता नयतु पतिर्यः प्रतिकाम्यः । त्वमस्यै धेह्योषधे ॥८॥**

Meaning

> To please us may the suitor come, O Agni, seeking this maid and
> bringing us good fortune.
> Approved by wooers, lovely in assemblies, may she be soon
> made happy with a husband.
> 2As bliss beloved by Soma, dear to Prayer, and stored by Arya-
> man,
> With the God Dhātar's truthfulness I work the bridal oracle.
> 3O Agni, may this woman find a husband. Then verily King Soma
> makes her happy.
> May she bear sons, chief lady of the household, blessed and
> bearing rule beside her consort.
> 4As this lair, Maghavan! that is fair to look on was dear to wild
> things as a pleasant dwelling,
> So may this woman here be Bhaga's darling. Loved by her lord
> and prizing his affection. p. a64
> 5Mount up, embark on Bhaga's ship, the full, the inexhaustible,
> Thereon bring hitherward to us the lover whom thou fain
> wouldst wed.
> 6Call out to him, O Lord of Wealth! Make thou the lover well-
> inclined.
> Set each on thy right hand who is a lover worthy of her choice.
> 7Here is the Bdellium and the gold, the Auksha and the bliss are
> here:
> These bring thee to the husbands, so to find the man whom thou.
> wouldst have.
> 8May Savitar lead and bring to thee the husband whom thy heart
> desires.
> O Plant, be this thy gift to her!

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything to get a good husband? The one you have shared is to get a good wife. I appreciate any further information.

Comment: @curiousseeker I updated the answer check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it.